# Install groovy package on focal

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.10

I'm running ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, everything is running fine with the services installed on the system.
I would however need a package updated as the current version has a bug that I need to solve. The package is "knxd".
The focal repository goes up to 0.14.30-1build1 but I need version 0.14.35-1 available in the groovy packages.
Is there anyway I can singularly upgrade this package to the version available in the groovy repository?

Thanks,
James

Comment: You can download any .deb package, and try to install is with `sudo dpkg  -i knxd_0.14.35-1_amd64.deb`. That often does not work because of unsatisfied dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is possible or not to install a `.deb` package of a newer Ubuntu version on an older Ubuntu release depends on whether the dependencies required by that package are met on the older release. Anyway, doing so is not supported in any ways.

Ubuntu has other software sources that may or may not contain a newer version. The "proposed" repository contains updated packages for testing, intended to roll out to the main repositories. That would mostly be bug fixes and safety patches, i.e., no major version upgrades. There is also a [Backport repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports), intended to host packages of newer Ubuntu versions that have been packaged to work with an older release. That may or may not contain a backport of the package you wish. If a package you would wish is not there, [proposals for backporting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports) can be made.

Apart from that, you depend on the existence of third party PPA's that may have compiled the newer version for your Ubuntu version. Ultimately, but that requires some (and depending, sometimes a lot) technical skills, one can compile the source code of the newer version of the software.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was going to go the compile route (I've done that before) but this application has so many compiling options it was way too much hassle. I ended up changing my universal repo from focal to groovy, updated the single package and then switched the repo back. Everything seems to be working, I'll see with time if it's stable

Comment: If it works, it will be OK. It means that the adequate dependencies are available. The point is that one - by design - cannot be sure it will work. One could say you are lucky this works. It would be advised to lock that version in synaptic package manager. Second, a less intrusive way to install that deb would have been to download it manually and then install the local copy, but hey, your approach also worked!

Answer (score 1):

This package can be installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system by simple [download from 20.10 repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/knxd) using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/knxd/knxd_0.14.35-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./knxd_0.14.35-1_amd64.deb
```

You are very lucky here, all dependencies will be satisfied automatically.